# Hudson with PMD-Plugin configured for android maven2 project

Tags: android, maven-2, hudson, pmd

I'm currently running into a problem using Hudson's PMD-plugin on a maven2-android project. 
The  part within my POM look like this:

```
  <reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugins</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <linkXref>true</linkXref>
          <sourceEncoding>UTF-8</sourceEncoding>
          <targetJdk>1.6</targetJdk>
          <rulesets>
            <ruleset>Where should this point?</ruleset>
          </rulesets>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting>
```

Unluckily I can't find any to the location of the android-ruleset. Anyone got the address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the latest PMD (4.2.5, February 2009), an `android.xml` file is included, with [Android-specific rules](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/rules/index.html#Android_Rules).

You could try and refer that file, a bit like in [this thread](http://java.net/projects/hudson/lists/commits/archive/2009-01/message/821).

```
<ruleset>rulesets/android.xml</ruleset>
```

Comment: You are completly right. Additionally I had a typo in my configuration, my artifactId should point to <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>, not "plugins".

Comment: @Robert: So, what did you end up putting in that "`<ruleset>`" element?

Comment: The corresponding line looks like this now:   <ruleset>rulesets/android.xml</ruleset>

Comment: @Robert: excellent. I have included it in the answer for more visibility.